# How to reinstall a gem using bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I did a `bundle show` and get the complete path to a gem directory.

Unfortunately, I removed the directory using `rm -r gem_path`. Then my rails app isn't working anymore. If I try start server or start rails console it outputs the following error:

> `<class:Application>`: uninitialized constant `MyAPP::Application::Gem` (NameError)

**What should I do to have it back?**

I tried `bundle install` or `bundle update` in hope of forcing the bundle to search the gem and install it back, but didn't work.

I also tried delete the `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle install`. Nothing changed, same error.

The gem in question is [**Act as taggable on**](http://rubygems.org/gems/acts-as-taggable-on).

Comment: If you delete Gemfile.lock and run bundle install again, what happens?

Comment: @DVG You should *not* do that. The lock file only specifies what versions should be installed, and doesn't have anything to do with whether or not a gem is installed.

Comment: Nevermind, looks like he already tried that.

Comment: @DVG I tried after your post. Sorry, Andrew Marshall, it wasn't that quick :(

Comment: What about if you `gem uninstall acts_as_taggable_on`, then run `bundle install` again?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First I did a `gem q --L`, the shortcut for `gem query --local`. It outputs me the all the local gems installed.

```
actionmailer (3.2.8, 3.2.6, 3.2.1, 3.1.0)
actionpack (3.2.8, 3.2.6, 3.2.1, 3.1.0)
activemodel (3.2.8, 3.2.6, 3.2.1, 3.1.0)
activerecord (3.2.8, 3.2.6, 3.2.1, 3.1.0)
activeresource (3.2.8, 3.2.6, 3.2.1, 3.1.0)
activesupport (3.2.8, 3.2.6, 3.2.1, 3.1.0)
acts-as-taggable-on (2.3.3)
...
```

And then, following DVG advice, I uninstalled the gem using its correct name `gem uninstall  acts-as-taggable-on` and ran `bundle install`. After that I was able to `rails c` or `rails s` again without any problem.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but the gem in question was installed **using** the `bundle` command and is **not present at all** in the output of `gem q --L`. It is only listed by `bundle list`, but the bare `gem` command cannot "see" it, so it cannot uninstall/reinstall it. `gem uninstall gem-in-question` finishes w/o errors (or any output for that matter), but has no effect on the contents of `bundle list`, and a subsequent `bundle install` just says "Your bundle is complete!".

What to do now?

Comment: Well, I have no idea. You could run a `bundle update` before listing, although I don't know if it's going to repair.

Comment: Have you tried `bundle exec gem uninstall the-gem-in-question`?  I know that `gem list` shows you all versions but `bundle exec gem list` show those gems specific to the bundle.

Comment: Szczepan - I had the same problem. I deleted my gem from Gemfile.lock but that didn't do it. I then ran a find under .rvm/gems for my gem name and deleted all instances - it was in a few bundler cache directories. Subsequently, running "bundle install" re-installed the gem. HTH.

Answer (score 85):

If using rbenv, this will let you completely uninstall and re-install a gem such as rmagick:

First: Try a simple uninstall/reinstall

```
gem uninstall rmagick
bundle install
```

If that doesn't work, you can remove all trace of the installed gem. Find your gem installation location:

```
bundle show rmagick
BUNDLE_DIR=$(dirname $(dirname $(bundle show rmagick)))
echo $BUNDLE_DIR
```

Your gem installation prefix will either be the default e.g. `~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0` or something you set e.g. `.vendor`

Clear out the gem directory:

```
rm -rf $BUNDLE_DIR/gems/rmagick-*
```

Clear out the compiled gem cache:

```
rm $BUNDLE_DIR/cache/rmagick*.gem
```

Also clear out bundler's spec cache:

```
rm $BUNDLE_DIR/specifications/rmagick*gemspec
```

Then you can re-install:

```
bundle install
```

Comment: I wanted to add that there might be binaries created that you've got to delete too, this was the case for me with the charlock_holmes gem. I had to delete the following path as well to get it to fully rebuild: `vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.0.0/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/`

Comment: This worked for me along with the tip from @lfxgroove. On my bundler-and-capistrano based installation, the relevant hierarchy was not under `vendor/` but `shared/bundle/ruby` etc.

Comment: When doing this with a gemfile, you need to do a bundle install without the gem in the Gemfile (commented out) to remove it from gemfile.lock, then add it back (uncomment) in order for it to reinstall

Answer (score 48):

You can always use:

`gem pristine acts-as-taggable-on`

pristine - Restores installed gems to pristine condition from files located in the gem cache

If you just want to restore the gem for the current project you should run:

`bundle exec gem pristine acts-as-taggable-on`

Comment: I use this every-time I screw up debugging with  `EDITOR=vim bundle open my-gem`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it does what the OP required

Comment: `bundle exec gem pristine` restores the gem from the local cache. So, if the gem exists only in your project, it would not work with `Bundler::GemNotFound` error. @Magne's answer followed by `bundle install` should do the job in that case.

Answer (score 13):

From project directory in terminal

```
gem uninstall gem_name
```

Comment: By far the best answer. After just `bundle install`

Answer (score 10):

If using [RVM](https://rvm.io/) with gems in `~/.rvm/`, this works if `bundle` is not re-installing a gem.

First, delete the gem source:

```
bundle show $GEM
rm -rf $PATH_TO_GEM
```

Clear out the compiled gem cache:

```
rm -rf ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-$RUBYVERSION[@$GEMSET]/cache/$GEM.gem
```

Also clear out bundler's spec cache:

```
rm -rf ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-$RUBYVERSION[@$GEMSET]/specifications/$GEM*gemspec
```

Then you can re-install:

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 10):

`bundle exec gem uninstall <gem_name>` -    uninstalls gem from the bundle (the `<app_root>/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/` path). This is equivalent to the answer @ioquatix gave, but is the slightly more convenient solution that he was looking for.

`gem uninstall <gem_name>`  -   uninstalls gem only from the global gemset in the system

Answer (score 7):

If you've installed into `./bundle/vendor` or similar, you need to remove the gem first but explicitly specify the GEM_HOME, e.g.

```
GEM_HOME=./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/ gem uninstall rmagick
```

This is by far the simplest way to uninstall gems installed using bundler into a vendor directory. Ideally, there would be a command `bundle uninstall` or `bundle reinstall`, etc.

If your goal is to simply reinstall, the following command will help:

```
GEM_HOME=./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/ gem uninstall rmagick && sudo -u http bundle install
```

If you're like me and have several web-applications under a directory (e.g. `/srv/http`), the following does it in all directories:

```
cd /srv/http
for d in ./*/ ; do (cd "$d" && sudo -u http GEM_HOME=./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/ gem uninstall --force rmagick && sudo -u http bundle install); done
```

Comment: The `bundle uninstall <gemname>` equivalent command you're looking for is `bundle exec gem uninstall <gemname>` Cheers https://stackoverflow.com/a/48094089/380607

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to reinstall rake, `gem pristine rake` will fail with `Skipped rake-10.X.X, it is a default gem` and bundle won't install it either, because it can't uninstall it.

If you're using rvm, it seems the easiest was is simply to do a `rvm reinstall 2.x.x`. At least for me, `rvm repair all` also didn't help.

The same probably goes for all other default gems. I'll just list them here so that the desperate googlers find some help:

- bigdecimal
- drip
- io-console
- json
- minitest
- psych
- rake
- rbtree
- rdoc
- test-unit