# How do I force Bundler to reinstall all of my gems?

Tags: bundler

How do I force Bundler to reinstall all of the gems in my gemfile? Or, how do I force Bundler to uninstall all of the gems it installed so I can then reinstall them myself?

---

I saw [rails bundle clean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905114/rails-bundle-clean), but this question explains how to remove gems that bundle installed but are no longer in the gemfile.

And [How to reinstall a gem using bundler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188833/how-to-reinstall-a-gem-using-bundler) explains how to reinstall a single gem. I would like to reinstall all of my gems at once.

Answer (score 262, accepted):

```
bundle install --redownload
```

See the reference for `bundle install`: https://bundler.io/v2.2/man/bundle-install.1.html

or

```
bundle install --force
```

For older versions of bundler

Comment: [DEPRECATED] The `--force` option has been renamed to `--redownload`

Comment: @Rimian I don't think `--force` option is deprecated. [Bundler docs](https://bundler.io/v2.0/man/bundle-install.1.html) say that `--redownload` is an alias for that option, but nothing about deprecating `--force`.

Comment: I copied that straight from std out. I guess we will find out at some point!

Comment: `--force` option still works but it raises a deprecation warning if you use it (bundler 2.1.4). I guess it will be totally deprecated in the next major upgrade

Comment: Note: If you're doing this locally to test that a live deployment will succeed, then add the `--deployment` switch to force the usage of the exact versions specified in your Gemfile (and ignore patch upgrades like ~> 0.3.2 which would normally upgrade to e.g. 0.3.6). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66791138/1852005

Answer (score 10):

Brutish but clever:

1. Comment out your entire Gemfile. (Don't delete it)
2. `bundle clean`
3. Restore your Gemfile.
4. `bundle install`

Answer (score 2):

You can also delete the `vendor` directory and do `bundle install` again.

Answer (score 2):

If you completely want to reinstall everything from scratch you can just, locate your gem dir, for example if you use rvm it would be ~/.rvm/gems
then locate your ruby version alongside with gemset for example ruby-2.7.0@some_particular_gemset (it will be a dir) and then just delete it.

```
rm -rf ruby-2.7.0@some_particular_gemset

bundle install
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to deal with gem problems can be to `sudo gem clean` instead of reinstalling everything